# Match multiple matrices by ID and loop a function across column IDs

Tags: r, matrix

I have got two matrices. Matrix 1 and matrix 2.

Matrix 1

```
     id1 id2 id3 id4 id5
row1 0.4 0.5 0.2 0.1 0.3
row2 1.1 1.2 1.5 0.8 1.0
```

Matrix 2

```
     id1 id2 id3 id4 id5
row1 0   2.1   2  1   2
row2 1     1   2  3   3 
row3 3   3.2   3  2   1
```

I would like to do the following

- Firstly, result a Matrix 3 has the same IDS as matrix 1 but only contains row 1.
- Secondly, result Matrix 4 which is a product of row2 of matrix 1 and entire Matrix 2.

Matrix3

```
    id1 id2 id3 id4 id5
row1 0.4 0.5 0.2 0.1 0.3
```

Matrix 4

```
    id1 id2 id3 id4 id5
row1 0   2.5  3  0.8 2
row2 1.1 1.2 3.0 2.4 3
row3 3.3 3.8 4.5 1.6 1
```

following that I would like to match the two matrices (matrix 3 and matrix 4) based on ID and run the following formula:

```
(1-matrix3$id)^2 + 2*(matrix3$id)*(1-matrix3$id)*(matrix4$id)+(matrix3$id)^2*(matrix4$id)^2
```

I would like to loop the formula across all the IDs please

Comment: @RHertel Matrix 4 is a product of row2 of matrix 1 and Matrix 2 i.e. I would extract row 2 from matrix 1 and generate product of the resulting matrix with matrix 2.

Comment: I will edit the latter part of the query (to make it clearer) in the comments section and leave the question untouched. thanks

Comment: Okay, I got that. `m4 <- t(t(m2)*m1[2,])` is another option. And I have now seen that it was also mentioned in @AEBilgrau answer.

Comment: The formula I have describe above needs to be applied for each row object under each ID column. So if there were 400 rows under column ID1, we would end up with 400 resulting objects under ID1 after applying the formula. If there were any "NA" records, I would code them as zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, another option

```
m3 <- m1[2,]
m4 <- m2*m3[col(m2)]
m4
#     id1  id2 id3 id4 id5
#row1 0.0 2.52 3.0 0.8   2
#row2 1.1 1.20 3.0 2.4   3
#row3 3.3 3.84 4.5 1.6   1
```

The second question based on guesswork would be

```
((1- m3)^2)[col(m4)] +  (2*m3*(1- m3))[col(m4)] * m4 + (m3^2)[col(m4)] * m4^2
 #         id1       id2     id3    id4 id5
 #row1  0.0100  7.974976 16.0000 0.7056   4
 #row2  1.2321  1.537600 16.0000 4.4944   9
 #row3 12.4609 19.430464 39.0625 2.1904   1
```

similar results got with @AEBilgrau's solution

```
t((1-mat3)^2 + 2*(mat3)*(1-mat3)*t(mat4) + (mat3)^2*t(mat4)^2)
#         id1       id2     id3    id4 id5
#row1  0.0100  7.974976 16.0000 0.7056   4
#row2  1.2321  1.537600 16.0000 4.4944   9
#row3 12.4609 19.430464 39.0625 2.1904   1
```

Comment: Hi @akrun for the last bit i.e.(1-matrix3$id)^2 + 2*(matrix3$id)*(1-matrix3$id)*(matrix4$id)+(matrix3$id)^2*(matrix4$id)^2, the resulting matrix would have the same dimensions as matrix 4.

Comment: @biostats_guy It is the same result as in the other post.

Answer (score 3):

For your first question you can use `sweep`:

```
m3 = m1[2,]
m4 = sweep(m2, m3, MARGIN=2, FUN="*")
#     id1  id2 id3 id4 id5
#row1 0.0 2.52 3.0 0.8   2
#row2 1.1 1.20 3.0 2.4   3
#row3 3.3 3.84 4.5 1.6   1
```

But still quite unclear what you expect as output by mentionning "for all ids"

Comment: Hi, My idea is that the function or formula will loop across along all the column ID's independently. So we would end up with a matrix with the same dimensions as matrix 4.

Answer (score 2):

I find your descripton somewhat hard to follow. It is e.g. not clear how you want to apply the 1 row of matrix 3 to the rows of matrix 4 in your formula.

If this

```
(1-mat$id1)^2 + 2*(mat3$id1)*(1-mat3$id1)*(mat4$id1)+(mat3$i1d)^2*(mat4$id1)^2
```

gives you the correct results for `id1`, then the last computation in following should be right.

Filling in the blanks by guessing, does this give you what you want?

```
# Load your data
mat1 <- as.matrix(read.table(header = TRUE, text="id1 id2 id3 id4 id5
row1 0.4 0.5 0.2 0.1 0.3
row2 1.1 1.2 1.5 0.8 1.0"))

mat2 <- as.matrix(read.table(header = TRUE, text="id1 id2 id3 id4 id5
row1 0   2.1   2  1   2
row2 1     1   2  3   3 
row3 3   3.2   3  2   1"))

# Create matrix 3
mat3 <- mat1["row1", ]
print(mat3)
#id1 id2 id3 id4 id5 
#0.4 0.5 0.2 0.1 0.3 

# Create matrix 4 (yet another option)
mat4 <- t(t(mat2)*mat1["row2", ])
print(mat4)
#     id1  id2 id3 id4 id5
#row1 0.0 2.52 3.0 0.8   2
#row2 1.1 1.20 3.0 2.4   3
#row3 3.3 3.84 4.5 1.6   1

# Compute results
res <- t((1-mat3)^2 + 2*(mat3)*(1-mat3)*t(mat4) + (mat3)^2*t(mat4)^2)
print(res)
#        id1    id2  id3    id4  id5
#row1 0.3600 3.0976 1.96 0.9604 1.69
#row2 1.0816 1.2100 1.96 1.2996 2.56
#row3 3.6864 5.8564 2.89 1.1236 1.00
```

We utilize here that matrices are stored in a column-major order and R's reuse rules.