# Multiply matrices conditional on the value of the element in the first matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have two matrices which I would like to multiply with each other. If matrix 1 has an object coded as 0 or 1 then a simple product will suffice. However if matrix 1 has an element coded as 2, then I would like to replace such elements with the square of respective matrix 2 elements.

Matrix 1

```
    id1 id2 id3 id4 id5
row1 0   2   2  1   2
row2 1   1   2  0   2 
row3 2   0   1  2   1
```

Matrix 2

```
     id1 id2 id3 id4 id5
row1 0.8 1.1 2.1 1.4 1.3
```

EDIT::

The product matrix will look like this:

Matrix 3

```
     id1  id2 id3 id4  id5

row1  0   1.2 4.4 1.4 1.69
row2  0.8 1.1 4.4  0  1.69
row3  0.64 0  2.1 1.96 1.3
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused what you mean by "objects." Do you mean the elements of the matrix? And when you say matrix multiplication, do you mean elementwise multiplication or true matrix multiplication?

Comment: I'm guessing that they want a "sweep" operation, i.e. values in a row of Matrix 1 multiplied by the corresponding element of Matrix 2 ... @biostats_guy, could you show the desired output?

Comment: @ZachTurn Yes, element wise multiplication is what I need to perform. I have edited the question to read elements instead of objects. thanks

Comment: @BenBolker I have edited in the output into the question. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Match multiple matrices by ID and loop a function across column IDs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37676149/match-multiple-matrices-by-id-and-loop-a-function-across-column-ids)

Comment: @biostats_guy isn't this similar to what you had asked yesterday?

Comment: @RonakShah It is partialy similar. Unlike previous matrix multiplication, I am replacing elements with the square of respective elements from a second matrix.

Comment: Do you mean the square or the square root when mat1 elements are 2? 0.89 is roughly the square root of 0.8, whereas 0.64 is the square.

Comment: Yes, the square rather than square root. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @biostats_guy if any of the answer solves your problem you can mark it as accepted by clicking on the tick mark below the vote button

Comment: @RonakShah ok. All three approaches listed below have worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following will produce the desired output

```
tempVec <- as.vector(t(mat1))
newVec <- ((tempVec == 2) * (mat2^2)) + ((tempVec == 1) * mat2)

newMat <- t(matrix(newVec, length(mat2)))
```

This produces the output:

```
> newMat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] 0.00 1.21 4.41 1.40 1.69
[2,] 0.80 1.10 4.41 0.00 1.69
[3,] 0.64 0.00 2.10 1.96 1.30
```

**data**

```
mat1 <- read.table(header=T, text="   id1 id2 id3 id4 id5
0   2   2  1   2
1   1   2  0   2 
2   0   1  2   1")
mat1 <- as.matrix(mat1)

mat2 <- c(0.8, 1.1, 2.1, 1.4, 1.3)
```

Comment: Perhaps the OP means square rather than square root, as 0.64 = 0.8^2, while 0.89 = sqrt(0.8) in row 3, column 1.

Comment: @imo Thank you. Yes, my mistake. I meant square and typed square root.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution,
In order to benefit from simple element-wise multiplication, we create a temp matrix named `m_tmp` which has the same dimension as `m1` and is row-wisely filled in with `m2`.

```
a=which(m1==2, arr.ind = T)    # find those indices in which 2 is placed
m1[a]=m_tmp[a]      # this will reflect the square in the next line      
m1=m1*m_tmp
```

Which produces this output:

```
> m1
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] 0.00 1.21 4.41 1.40 1.69
[2,] 0.80 1.10 4.41 0.00 1.69
[3,] 0.64 0.00 2.10 1.96 1.30
```

**DATA**

```
m1=structure(c(0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1), .Dim = c(3L, 5L))
m2=structure(c(0.8, 1.1, 2.1, 1.4, 1.3), .Dim = c(1L, 5L))
m_tmp=matrix(m2, 3, 5, byrow = T)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 m1 <- structure(c(0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1), .Dim = c(3L, 5L))
 m2 <- structure(c(0.8, 1.1, 2.1, 1.4, 1.3), .Dim = c(1L, 5L))
```

In general your idea is to take a product. Your rule might be explained as such:

> If an entry from a row from `m1` is `0` or `1`, multiply that entry times its corresponding component from `m2`. If an entry from a row from `m1` is `2`, multiply its corresponding component from `m2` times itself.

So I think you just need to take the product of each row times `m2` where the entries of the row that equal `2` are replaced with the corresponding entries of `m2` (i.e. squaring those entries). I do it here using `apply()`.

```
m3 <- apply(m1, 1, function(row){
   equals2 <- row==2
   row[equals2] <- m2[equals2]
   row*m2
 })

## dont forget to transpose
m3 <- t(m3)
```

Final product:

```
> m3
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] 0.00 1.21 4.41 1.40 1.69
[2,] 0.80 1.10 4.41 0.00 1.69
[3,] 0.64 0.00 2.10 1.96 1.30
```

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated.